# Unsupported URL protocol in git provider error

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-2015, gitlab

I have two separate PCs that connect to the same Gitlab repo. Both running Visual Studio Update 3 and using Team Explorer with Git. On one PC, I have no problem updating the project and then pushing the commits to the remote repo. On the other PC however any operation (push or fetch or sync) will fail with an `Unsupported URL protocol` error, although originally I managed to clone the repo. I suspect it doesn't like something in the connection string, since I can commit and sync the repo using command line git (version 2.9.2 so fairly recent). What is the cause of this error and is there a workaround?

Comment: Since the Git bash is working on the other computer, one workaround is to just use the bash.  You could try comparing Gitlab connection settings between the two computers.

Comment: yes, that's the current workaround I'm using. Is there a way to check some sort of connection log or the connection string, since it's complaining about the URL. I tried URL rewriting but that didn't work.

Comment: Compare the settings from both Gitlabs.  One is working, so you can use this as a reference.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have checked the difference between the two local repos, and `git remote -v` on PC1 gives:

> origin https://gitlab.com/ ...

while on PC2:

> origin git@gitlab.com: ...

After further investigation it appears that the old version of [LibGit2](https://libgit2.github.com/) which VS2015 Update3 uses lacks SSH support. The first repo was the original and created in VS, the second repo was cloned via a command-line, hence the SSH connection string.

The workaround is to change the connection string in `.git/config` to

> url = https://gitlab.com/ ...

If one absolutely needs SSH than it is possible to recompile gitlib2, or use command line git which works. It might be possible to use other Git Source Providers in VS2015, however I haven't tested it. (for example [Git Source Control Provider 2015](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/51e11ccc-6334-4873-912d-bf5025eb115d))